# How to make application faster using sync framework.?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am working in MS Sync Framework 2.1 .I have 15-16 table that i need to synchronized.

I am doing code(in win form C#) which is work fine.I created provisions for each of the tables.

My code work and sequentially sync up one by one tables.Application takes approximately 10 min for download 9500 records from remote database server .But its seemed too slow. How i can speed up downloading records ?.

Can i use thread to downloading records, so all threads work parallely and might be application time will be decreases for download.

Is it thread safe or is server might be crash if hit rate (requesting data by applications) is increase?

How i can increase application speed for downloading record in winform C#

Answer (score 0):

enable Sync Framework Tracing and have a look at where its spending most of its time, then decide how to optimize that part.